# Android Map App Crashing on Device at Startup

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I've been having this problem repeatedly when using the Google Maps API through Android Studio. It compiles fine, no errors, but when running on my device, it always crashes on startup. I'm using a Huawei P90 Lite (Marshmallow 6.0).

Thank you so much for your help!
Joe S.

Here is the code:

MapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.jonathan.parq01;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import  android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.Date;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor accelerometer;
private float last_x, last_y, last_z;

long lastUpdate = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    // setup the accelerometer
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;

    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = event.values[0]; // x value
        float y = event.values[1]; // y value
        float z = event.values[2]; // z value

        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (Math.abs(curTime - lastUpdate) > 2000)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String currentDateTime = date.format(new Date());

            lastUpdate = curTime;

            if (Math.abs(last_x - x) > 10)
            {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.23062, -80.42178))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
                        .title("Hey you moved the x axis" + currentDateTime));
            }

            if (Math.abs(last_y - y) > 10)
            {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.26062, -80.42188))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                        .title("Hey you moved the y axis" + currentDateTime));
            }

            if (Math.abs(last_z - z) > 10)
            {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.24062, -80.43178))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                        .title("Hey you moved the z axis" + currentDateTime));
            }

            last_x = x;
            last_y = y;
            last_z = z;
        }
    }
}

public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(37.229, 80.424)).title("Virginia Tech"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(37.229, 80.424), 14.9f));
}
}
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jonathan.parq01.MapsActivity" />
```

I have also added the Google Maps API Key to the appropriate xml file.

```
AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jonathan.parq01">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Stack trace:

```
03-01 15:41:16.021 9132-9132/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-01 15:41:16.038 9132-9138/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-01 15:41:16.079 9132-9132/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown        path: /data/app/com.example.jonathan.parq01-2/lib/arm64
03-01 15:41:16.086 9132-9132/? I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.jonathan.parq01, real application class is null.
03-01 15:41:16.383 9132-9132/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.jonathan.parq01-2/lib/arm64
03-01 15:41:16.415 9132-9132/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
03-01 15:41:16.526 9132-9132/? I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
03-01 15:41:16.603 9132-9132/? I/zzai: Making Creator dynamically
03-01 15:41:16.668 9132-9132/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000027/n/arm64-v8a
03-01 15:41:16.679 9132-9132/? I/System.out: [/system/bin/getprop,    debug.mapview.logs]
03-01 15:41:16.679 9132-9132/? I/System.out: null
03-01 15:41:16.679 9132-9132/? I/System.out: null
03-01 15:41:16.679 9132-9132/? I/System.out: Calling by::className:com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.q  MethodName:a
03-01 15:41:16.704 9132-9132/? I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 10298000
03-01 15:41:16.708 9132-9132/? I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 10298448
03-01 15:41:16.708 9132-9132/? I/System.out: [/system/bin/getprop, debug.mapview.renderer]
03-01 15:41:16.708 9132-9132/? I/System.out: null
03-01 15:41:16.708 9132-9132/? I/System.out: null
03-01 15:41:16.709 9132-9132/? I/System.out: Calling by::className:com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.q  MethodName:a
03-01 15:41:16.732 9132-9132/? I/System.out: [/system/bin/getprop, debug.mapview.streetview]
03-01 15:41:16.732 9132-9132/? I/System.out: null
03-01 15:41:16.732 9132-9132/? I/System.out: null
03-01 15:41:16.732 9132-9132/? I/System.out: Calling by::className:com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.q  MethodName:a
03-01 15:41:16.781 9132-9132/? I/System.out: [/system/bin/getprop, debug.mapview.gmmserver]
03-01 15:41:16.781 9132-9132/? I/System.out: null
03-01 15:41:16.781 9132-9132/? I/System.out: null
03-01 15:41:16.782 9132-9132/? I/System.out: Calling by::className:com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.q  MethodName:a
03-01 15:41:16.952 9132-9157/? I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
03-01 15:41:16.982 9132-9157/? I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
03-01 15:41:17.316 9132-9132/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9132 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you please paste the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks, I added it above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the SHA1 key for making a google map app.you can get your sha1 key by typing the following command on the command prompt:-

keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: Thank you, but when running this command, I get the following error:
"java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist"

Comment: keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore      (use this command.)

Comment: Sorry, but am still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a Key-Store and place it where it is required.
~I have something similar with my Android Studio where it always looks for a Key-Store file in the wrong location.

The needed file is still present, but needs to be copied from the folder "Above" where it is referencing. Which is to say, in the directory of the parent folder sits the files, where Android Studio is looking in the Child folder of this one (Nested incorrectly)

You can take the correct file, mine is (~.android.android\debug.keystore), and then copy it into the correct directory, app~.android.android\debug.keystore.~

This helped me immensely, hope it can for you as well.

From a variety of Stack Overflow research, culminating with trial and error!